# form button with javascript not function but adding "/?" to the end of my url

Tags: javascript, html, forms, api, azure

I have some simple code...
HTML:

```
    <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id='query'>
        <button type="button" name="submitButton" id="submitBtn2" onclick="submitBtn()">SEND</button>
    </form>


<iframe id="results" name="results" onload='javascript:resizeIframe(this);' src="javascript:void(0);"></iframe>
```

Javascript:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function resizeIframe(obj) {
    obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
  }
</script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function submitBtn() {
    var search = document.getElementById('query').value;
    console.log("search:" +search);
    console.log(search.length)
    if (search.length>0){
      document.getElementById('results').src = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + escape('<h2>'+ search +'</h2>');
      userAction(search);
    }
  }
</script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function userAction(res) {

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var api = 'myAPI';
    var url= api + res;
    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.onload = function () {

        var data = this.response;

        if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
            document.getElementById('results').src = "data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + escape(data);
        } else {
            console.log('error');
        }
    }
    request.send();
}

</script>
```

Issue:
If I have a blank `query` field - then everything works as it should when I click the button (not changing anything - and I can see the logs from inside `submitBtn()`), however if I enter a value into the `query` field then when I click the button, it does not trigger my `submitBtn()` function.

Instead it redirects my url to "mycurrenturl"/? - I am not sure why it does this and adds `/?` to the end of my url.

The api I am trying to hit is an Azure functions HttpTrigger. I do not get the `console.log`s from within my `submitBtn()` function, so I am assuming it is an issue with the form when there is a value inputted?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The language attribute for script elements was removed a long, long time ago. The type attribute is redundant for *text/javascript*. :-)

Comment: What happens if you get rid of the `<form>` tag? If you're using AJAX, there's no need for a `<form>` around the inputs.

Comment: @Barmar—was thinking the same thing, but the button isn't a submit button so shouldn't submit the form anyway. A form provides easy access to controls (but the OP isn't taking advantage of that).

Comment: @RobG I also thought the button shouldn't submit anything, but it sure sounds like it is. Maybe the user is pressing the Enter key rather than clicking the button.

Comment: @Barmar There's certainly need for it. Semantics, accessibility, HTML validation, etc.

Comment: OK, keep the form, but add `action="#"` to it so it can't actually submit anything.

Comment: @Barmar this adds `/?#` to the url now

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/x5qjn4mz/10/ I had to change from GET to POST because of the way jsfiddle's API works, but otherwise it's essentially the same as your code. I suspect there's something else going on in your application.

Comment: @Barmar having looked into it further - the issue seems to be when pressing enter - does this clear up the issue?

Comment: You should put that in the question. It specifically says that the problem happens when clicking the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is only happening when you press Enter in the text field. That submits the form, it doesn't trigger a click on the button. The solution is to use the form's `onsubmit` handler:

```
<form onsubmit="submitBtn(); return false;">
```

`return false;` prevents the default submission action from happening.

If you do this, you can also remove the `onclick` from the submit button, and change it to `type="submit"`. Then clicking on the button will trigger a form submit, which will then run the above code.